# Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome crashes with Nvidia 1050 ti driver 410 and Xorg, but not Wayland

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, xorg, wayland

Question is pretty self-explanatory. If I install the Nvidia properietary driver and enable it with

```
 sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and reboot, I cannot log into Xorg (it immediately crashes and returns me to the login screen). Wayland works fine.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: Install inxi & post results of inxi -G

Answer (score 0):

I am not the only one with this problem!

I've tried this on Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.10.

Have you tried installing nvidia-driver-390?

I have had limited success with:

```
sudo apt purge nivdia-driver-* gdm3 && sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 gdm3
sudo reboot.
```

When I get that to work, I can get HDMI to work, but laptop screen freezes.

I am yet to try more of my luck with Intel Drivers.